# How to avoid the attribute interchanging in xml while using XML::Twig in perl

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

In my input xml file we are doing some conversions work in perl. And we need to have the xml file with indentation. Hence we are using the Module `XML::Twig` (Simple way) for pretty indent.

In perl code:

```
XML::Twig->new( pretty_print => 'indented')
     ->parsefile( $input )
     ->print_to_file( $input);
```

Input:
     `<contrib contrib-type="author" id="U94028797" corresp="yes">`

After doing this function the tool has been interchanging the attribute's in xml elements.

Output:
     `<contrib contrib-type="author" corresp="yes" id="U94028797">`

Anyone give suggestion to avoid this and it would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `keep_atts_order` option when you create the twig: [docs](http://xmltwig.org/xmltwig/twig_dev.html#METHODS_XML_Twig_new_keep_atts_order)

You will need [Tie::IxHash](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::IxHash) to be installed.

Note that XML tools should not care at all about the order of the attributes.

Comment: ... and this is yet another reason why parsing with regex is a horrible idea! :)